# Aarch64 u-boot compile issue

Tags: u-boot, arm64

I am currently experiencing a really strange bug when compiling for u-boot:

The vector

```
init_fnc_t *init_sequence[] ={...}
```

is filled with 0's / NULLs instead of function pointers. I thought I outsmarted the compiler by calling all those functions 'by hand'. However this bug has even more ramifications as the driver struct also gets 0 / NULL pointers:

```
static struct serial_device my_serial_drv = {
    .name = "my_serial",
    .start = my_serial_init,
    .stop = NULL,
    .setbrg = my_serial_setbrg,
    .putc = my_serial_putc,
    .puts = my_serial_puts,
    .getc = my_serial_getc,
    .tstc = my_serial_tstc,
};
```

which, of course, when I call

```
 'my_serial_drv'->start();
```

sets the pc to 0 and subsequently crashes everything.

Fun fact: the .name reaches the binary, so the .data sections are probably fine once they are set.

I have tested this with aarch64-linux-gnu-*-4.7 and aarch64-linux-gnu-*-4.9 binaries.
You can find 4.9 from: 
http://releases.linaro.org/latest/components/toolchain/binaries.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: What release of u-boot? And have you tried using the ELDK compiler from denx? http://www.denx.de/wiki/view/DULG/ELDKAvailability if there's a compile issue with other compilers I always fall back to the ELDK.

Comment: ELDK does not support arm64 ( or aarch64 ).
I have started working from an u-boot git clone, last public commit : c9aab0f9dd23fddcebf5984dc19e62b514e759a7 on Mon Apr 21 21:01:35 2014 +0200

Comment: c9aab0f9dd23fddcebf5984dc19e62b514e759a7 was ages ago! Though your issue seems to be toolchain related and not u-boot related. If you browse through the u-boot mailing list there is no one reporting the same issue as you. http://news.gmane.org/gmane.comp.boot-loaders.u-boot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The u-boot.bin file seems allright. After investigating *why* this works I saw that u-boot's make is running a separate command to fix the bin:

```
start=$(aarch64-linux-gnu-nm u-boot | grep __rel_dyn_start | cut -f 1 -d ' ');
end=$(aarch64-linux-gnu-nm u-boot | grep __rel_dyn_end | cut -f 1 -d ' '); 
tools/relocate-rela u-boot.bin 0x3e900000 $start $end
```

(these were a single line but I split it for readability )